# Visual Studio/WPConnect Unable to Connect to WP7 Device

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-7, zune

For some reason, I'm no longer able to connect and deploy to my wp7 device. Zune does not show the phone as being connected, despite the fact that it is connected and the phone shows that it's being charged ... and the wpconnect tool gives the following error:

> Failed to connect to the device.
>   Ensure that the device is completely
>   booted and  is connected to the PC.
>   (0x80070103)

I rebooted the phone, and I've deployed to it before, so it's definitely developer unlocked. I verified that my computer has internet access. Any other troubleshooting thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a short term workaround try using the Application Deployment utility to deploy the xap file.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I run into this all the time. Simply restart your phone and connect again. Make sure you plug in and unplug the phone several times, waiting at least a minute if it doesn't work.

In short, it's temperamental, Keep trying.

Comment: that's the strange part, I did restart it several times last night to no avail. Very strange, I tried it again this morning and all was working fine :-P

Comment: Yeah it's annoying. I wonder if it's the coupling with Zune that is making it unstable.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have switched off WiFi and Bluetooth on your phone.

I have found that I cannot deploy when Wifi and Bluetooth are switched on - even though Zune is syncing music and other content in the usual fashion. The error messages are frustratingly unhelpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When I changed the Project properties target OS to 7.1 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Only restoring to the previous OS version helped me.
Also I would that it usually happens when internet sharing is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the problem!

When I had this problem a few days ago, I had been charging my phone (Lumia 900) using a faulty charger which keeps on getting disconnected. And now that I've changed the cable and charger, it started working again! 
I had the same problem with my previous phone as well (HTC Mozart), and I had a bad cable back then, but never made the connection (geddit?) between the problem and the cable...

My theory is that when the phone is running on bad power supply/not getting enough power, it sets a flag in the registry, which throws that error.

Answer (score 0):

Also, bizarrely I just found that if you have internet sharing turned on then it won't let you connect.

Answer (score 0):

Any of above mentioned did not work for me. I had many different error messages (included the 0x80070103)

What did is this:

1. Go to https://dev.windowsphone.com, uregister your phone.
2. Launch registration tool ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Phone Registration\PhoneReg.exe")
3. Unregister in tool from 2) too (if it is showing still as
   registered).
4. Now disconnect phone and connect it again
5. Register phone in tool from 2)